# android SupportActionBar how to remove divider below

Tags: android, android-support-library

using SupportActionBar and with a custom view.

I have this white line below my action bar that i can't remove:

[image]

how can i remove it ??

this is my action bar style:

```
<!-- menu button -->

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/actionbar_menu_imageview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:src="@drawable/button_action_bar_menu" />

<!-- spinner -->

<ProgressBar       
    android:id="@+id/actionbar_spinner"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/actionbar_profile_picture"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<!-- title -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/actionbar_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Title"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

<!-- profile picture -->

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/actionbar_profile_picture"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/white_circle"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/icon" />
```

Comment: check if margin top or padding set to layout

Comment: Try to change the action bar style using this tool by Jeff Gilfelt http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

Comment: @PankajKumar couldn't find any - updated the question with my layout

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/). It lets you create beautiful action bars that actually follow the design guidelines, unlike your action bar.